# End of file error when adding a stored procedure to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a stored procedure and encountered the following error:

> ERROR at line 11: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null
>   pragma raise return select update while with close    current delete
>   fetch lock insert    open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit
>   forall merge pipe

the code that i am using:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE search_car244ikYKOETEO
IS
long TAXICAR.LONGITUDE%type;
lat TAXICAR.LATITUDE%type;
BEGIN

select LONGITUDE,LATITUDE
into long,lat
from taxiCar,driver
where driver.STATEOFDRIVER='free' and taxiCar.name='taxiRiyadh'
END;
```

Once I correct the missing semicolon at the end, I get a different error

```
ERROR at line 8: PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please put some effort in your question otherwise they will be closed quickly. That means appropriate tags, normal formatting and a good description of the actual problem.

Comment: You are missing the closing semicolon `;` after your SQL statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SELECT` statement is missing a semicolon at the end.  `LONG` is also a reserved word so you'll need to choose a different variable name.  I'd strongly suggest adopting a standard prefix for local variables to differentiate them from column names.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE search_car244ikYKOETEO
IS
  l_long TAXICAR.LONGITUDE%type; -- <-- LONG is a reserved word
  l_lat  TAXICAR.LATITUDE%type;
BEGIN
  select LONGITUDE,
         LATITUDE
    into l_long,
         l_lat
    from taxiCar,driver
   where driver.STATEOFDRIVER='free' 
     and taxiCar.name='taxiRiyadh'; -- <-- A semicolon terminates a SQL statement
END;
```

Assuming there is some relationship between the `taxiCar` and `driver` tables, I would assume that you are missing a join condition as well (something like `and taxiCar.carID = driver.carID` if there is a foreign key in `driver` that references the primary key of `taxiCar`).

Once your procedure compiles, it will throw an error if the `SELECT` statement returns anything other than 1 row.  It seems likely that it would be possible for there to be 0 free drivers or more than 1 free driver so it seems unlikely that you want a `SELECT ... INTO` here.  Perhaps you want to iterate through the rows using a cursor.  Perhaps you want to `BULK COLLECT` the data into a collection.  Perhaps you want to create a view rather than a stored procedure.

If you want to iterate through the rows using a cursor and print out the longitudes

```
create or replace PROCEDURE search_car244ikYKOETEO
IS
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (select LONGITUDE,
                   LATITUDE
              from taxiCar,
                   driver
             where driver.STATEOFDRIVER='free' 
               and taxiCar.name='taxiRiyadh')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( x.longitude );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: there's also error :(///ERROR at line 8: PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
6. select LONGITUDE,LATITUDE
7. into long,lat
8. from taxiCar,driver
9. where driver.STATEOFDRIVER='free' and taxiCar.name='taxiRiyadh';
10. END;//

Comment: @user1375518 - Updated my answer.  The problem now is that `LONG` is a reserved word.

Comment: it's work !..but when executing i have this error : ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: i think the problem because there's not cursor.. how i can make cursor in my code ?

Comment: @user1375518 - I updated my answer with an example of using a cursor.

Comment: but there no "cursor" word in code!..also what maen X in "FOR x IN"..and i put in <<do something>>.. the flowing:DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(taxiCar.LONGITUDE || ' ' ||taxiCar.LATITUDE);..it's correct?.....and also after that i got error massage: ERROR at line 11: PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'TAXICAR.LONGITUDE' not allowed in this context
1. create or replace PROCEDURE search_car244ikYKOETEO 
2. IS
3. BEGIN

Comment: i tried this :create or replace PROCEDURE search_car244ikYKOETEO AS
CURSOR c_taxi
IS
  select LONGITUDE,LATITUDE
  from taxiCar,driver
 where driver.STATEOFDRIVER='free' and TAXICAR.name='taxiRiyadh';

BEGIN

    FOR v_taxi IN c_taxi LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_taxi.LONGITUDE || ' ' ||v_taxi.LATITUDE);
      END LOOP;
END;.:...........but i have duplicate answers or rows,,,i have result like this : 24.690618 46.711539
24.690618 46.711539
24.690618 46.711539

Statement processed.

Comment: @user1375518  - As I said in my answer, you are very likely missing a join condition.  In my answer, I was using an implicit cursor rather than an explicit cursor.  I updated my answer with the syntax to reference columns in the implicit cursor.

Comment: i copy your code and paste it in my oracle..but also i have duplicate answers or rows like this                                    24.690618 46.711539
24.690618 46.711539
24.690618 46.711539                                                      why?.. suppose to show me one answer with one and only               24.690618 46.711539

Comment: @user1375518 - Yes, as I've said now a few times, you are probably missing a join condition.  You haven't posted your table definitions so I don't know how the two tables are related.  In may answer, I provided an example of the sort of join condition you probably want (of course, I'm guessing at how the tables are related)

Comment: Really!..the problem was messing the a join condition!..it's give correct out put!....thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanx aloooooooooot :)